# JavaScript == $0 Never Seen Before

Tags: javascript, video

I'm inserting a video tag into a webpage but the video for some reason doesn't show up even though it's found the video resource.

I looked in the console and found `== $0` which I've never seen before and didn't know if it had something to do with it.

Does anyone know what this means?

[image]

Comment: `$0` is just an identifier. You can use `var $0 = whatever`

Answer (score 4):

That isn't JavaScript. It is just a marker to tell you which DOM element you have selected in the DOM inspector.

You can type `$0` in the Console to get the [currently selected element](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#0-4).

Comment: You can also use `$1` to get the previously selected element.

Comment: And `$$0` to get them as either a node list or html element list (I can't remember which)